# Wordpress edit.php category filter to show only posts from direct category and not posts from it child category

Tags: categories

On the admin edit.php page, when i filter the posts by a particular category (using the built in dropdown) it shows all the posts related to that category, and all the posts that are 'under' its child categories.

How can i change this functionality, so when i filter by a category it only shows posts from that category only, no child categories posts.

Will appreciate any help, as i couldnt find any info about this online.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Display posts that have this category (not children of that category), using category id:

```
$cat_post = new WP_Query( 'category__in=4' ); // you will replace the 4 with your category ID
if( $cat_post->have_posts()){
  while( $cat_post->have_posts()):
    $cat_post->the_post();

    // NOW RIGHT THE CODE AS PER YOUR DESIGN

  endwhile;
}
```